# Json Schema dependency on outer field

Tags: jsonschema

Given a json structure like this

```
{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "billing_address": "123 main st",
 "payment_details":{"credit_card": 55555555}
}
```

I need to make 'billing_address' a required field if payment_details.credit_card exists.

I've started from this example that achieves so if both fields were at the same level of nesting

```
{
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "number" }
  },

  "required": ["name"],

  "dependencies": {
    "credit_card": {
      "properties": {
        "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["billing_address"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, what is the syntax to require this field that is one level above the dependant field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's too complicated for 'dependencies', so we go back to an if/then/else clause for that.  We place these keywords at the top level, where the required field needs to be. In pseudocode: "if there is a payment_details property present, and it has a credit_card property, then require billing_address."

```
{
  ...,
  "if": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "payment_details" ],
    "properties": {
      "payment_details": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [ "credit_card" ]
      }
    },
  "then": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "billing_address" ]
  }
}
```

Note that the "type" and "required" keywords are required here -- as data of different types (for example an array) will cause object-specific keywords like "properties" and "required" to always evaluate to true.

Comment: Where are `if` and `then` defined. Is this new?

Comment: Those keywords were added in draft 7 - https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ether! this worked, but only after adding the credit card as a property, in the `if` section.
the full if statement looks like this

```
"if": {
       "type": "object",
  "required": ["payment_details"],      
       "properties": {
              "payment_details": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "credit_card": {}
            },
                        "required": ["credit_card"]
        }}},
```

the full json schema looks like this

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#", 
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "payment_details": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "credit_card": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
,    
"if": {
       "type": "object",
  "required": ["payment_details"],      
       "properties": {
              "payment_details": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "credit_card": {}
            },
                        "required": ["credit_card"]
        }}},
  "then": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "billing_address" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `"properties": { "credit_card": {} },` just means "if this property is present, then true", which is the same as not having it there at all. If there is a difference of behaviour with it vs. without it, that sounds like a bug in your evaluator.