# How to validate child element checking values in parent elemnt using JsonSchema validation

Tags: api, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following json schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "orderNumber",
    "status",
    "orderType",
    "orderLines"
  ],
  "properties": {

    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "ORDERED",
        "CANCELLED"
      ]
    },
    "orderType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "SALES_ORDER",
        "RETURN_ORDER"
      ]
    },
    "lines": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "lineNumber"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "lineNumber": {
                "type": "integer",
              },
              "returnReason": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "BUYERS_REMORSE",
                  "DELIVERY_TIMEFRAME"
                ]
              },
              "cancellationReason": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "BUYERS_REMORSE",
                  "DELIVERY_TIMEFRAME"
                ]
              },
              "parentSONumber": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parentSOlineNumber": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

I need to do the following validation

If status = "CANCELLED", then I need to make the field lines.cancellationReason to be required. Also if orderType = "RETURN_ORDER", then I want to make the fields parentSONumber, parentSOlineNumber and returnReason as required. 'lineNumber' is mandatory always.

I was trying to do the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "orderNumber",
    "status",
    "orderType",
    "orderLines"
  ],
  "properties": {

    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "ORDERED",
        "CANCELLED"
      ]
    },
    "orderType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "SALES_ORDER",
        "RETURN_ORDER"
      ]
    },
    "lines": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "object",
            "allOf": [
              {
                "if": {
                  "properties": {
                    "orderType": {
                      "const": "RETURN_ORDER"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "then": {"required": ["parentSOlineNumber", "parentSONumber", "returnReason"]}
                },
                {
                "if": {
                  "properties": {
                    "status": {
                      "const": "CANCELLED"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "then": {"required": ["cancellationReason"]}
                },
                {
                  "required": [
                    "lineNumber"
                  ],
                }
                }
              }
            ],
            "properties": {
              "lineNumber": {
                "type": "integer",
              },
              "returnReason": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "BUYERS_REMORSE",
                  "DELIVERY_TIMEFRAME"
                ]
              },
              "cancellationReason": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "BUYERS_REMORSE",
                  "DELIVERY_TIMEFRAME"
                ]
              },
              "parentSONumber": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parentSOlineNumber": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Can someone help with this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json Schema dependency on outer field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459177/json-schema-dependency-on-outer-field)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying something like this:

```
 ...
 "allOf": [
    {
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "status": {
                    "const": "CANCELLED"
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "properties": {
                "lines": {
                    "items": {
                        "required": ["cancellationReason"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "if": {
            "properties": {
                "orderType": {
                    "const": "RETURN_ORDER"
                }
            }
        },
        "then": {
            "properties": {
                "lines": {
                    "items": {
                        "required": [
                            "parentSONumber",
                            "parentSOlineNumber",
                            "returnReason"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 ],
 "properties": {

    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "ORDERED",
        "CANCELLED"
      ]
    },
    "orderType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "SALES_ORDER",
        "RETURN_ORDER"
      ]
    },
...
```

So, instead of trying to reference values at a higher nesting level (which isn't possible), you can define the if - then at the higher nesting level, and make restrictions on the deeper values in the if - then subschemas, and apply these patch-like partial schemas.

Notes:

- please test this solution. It is a nontrivial schema, and I didn't test it
- if you can't use "const", because your tooling doesn't support it, you can replace it with a single-element enumeration like `"enum": ["CANCELLED"]`
- if you can't use `"if"` - `"then"` , then you can rewrite the `if A then B` predicate to `not A or B` which can be expressed in json-schema like `"not": {"anyOf": [ A-subschema , B-subschema ]}`